# Python missing __exit__ method

Tags: python

Some background: I work in a large bank and I'm trying to re-use some Python modules, which I cannot change, only import. I also don't have the option of installing any new utilities/functions etc (running Python 2.6 on Linux).

I've got this at present:

In my module:

```
from common.databaseHelper import BacktestingDatabaseHelper

class mfReportProcess(testingResource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = BacktestingDatabaseHelper.fromConfig('db_name')
```

One of the methods called within the 'testingResource' class has this:

```
 with self.db as handler:
```

which falls over with this:

```
with self.db as handler:
AttributeError: 'BacktestingDatabaseHelper' object has no attribute '__exit__'
```

and, indeed, there is no `__exit__` method in the 'BacktestingDatabaseHelper' class, a class which I cannot change.

However, this code I'm trying to re-use works perfectly well for other apps - does anyone know why I get this error and no-one else? 
Is there some way of defining `__exit__` locally?

Many thanks in advance.

EDITED to add:

I've tried to add my own class to setup DB access but can't get it to work - added this to my module:

```
class myDB(BacktestingDatabaseHelper): 
    def __enter__(self): 
        self.db = fromConfig('db_name') 
    def __exit__(self): 
        self.db.close()
```

and added:

```
self.db = myDB
```

into my **init** attribute for my main class but I get this error:

```
with self.db as handler:
TypeError: unbound method __enter__() must be called with myDB instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Any suggestions as to how to do this properly?

Comment: They are using a different version of the module or they are not using  `BacktestingDatabaseHelper` as a context manager

Comment: You would have to know what the real `__enter__` and `__exit__` do, and do the same. If the same code works for other people in your company, I really suggest you to check the version and contents of each the common modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means that `BacktestingDatabaseHelper` is not designed to be used in a `with` statement. Sounds like the classes `testingResource` and `BacktestingDatabaseHelper` are not compatible with each other (perhaps your version of `common.databaseHelper` is out of date).

Comment: I'm coming round to the idea that my version is wrong/old but waiting for a member of the dev team to advise.

Comment: Aaggh - the dev guy now tells me he installed the wrong package for me!! Very sorry to all and many thanks for all your answers.

Comment: @user996166; so put that as **'EDIT:'** in the first line of your question!!

Answer (score 11):

Using the `with` protocol assumes that the object used in `with` implements the [context manager protocol](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types).

Basically this means that the class definition should have `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods defined. If you use an object without these, python will throw an `AttributeError` complaining about the missing `__exit__` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

As you cannot change the `with` statement, you must add a class deriving from `BacktestingDatabaseHelper` which adds appropriate `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` functions and use this instead.

Here is an example which tries to be as close to the original as possible:

```
class myDB(BacktestingDatabaseHelper): 
    def __enter__(self): 
        return self
    def __exit__(self): 
        self.db.close()
    def fromConfig(self, name):
        x = super(myDB, self).fromConfig(name)
        assert isinstance(x, BacktestingDatabaseHelper)
        x.__class__ = myDB # not sure if that really works
[...]
self.db=myDB.fromConfig('tpbp')
```

The problem is, however, that I am not sure what the `__enter__` is supposed to return. If you take `MySQLdb`, for example, the context manager of the connection creates a cursor representing one transaction. If that's the case here as well, wou have to work out something else...

Comment: @user996166 I added an example how it could work - maybe. `self.db = myDB` just assigns the class. Maybe you could as well try with `self.db = myDB()`, although I doubt if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use the common version of 'fromConfig' (which I can't change) as it has important parameters/variables to setup.

Comment: In my example above, you use it (via the `super` stuff) and just change its result's class.

Answer (score 2):

The 'with' keyword is basically a [shortcut](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) for writing out:

```
try:
    // Do something
finally:
    hander.__exit__()
```

which is useful if your `handler` object is using up resources (like, for example, an open file stream).  It makes sure that no matter what happens in the 'do something' part, the resource is released cleanly.

In your case, your handler object doesn't have an `__exit__` method, and so `with` fails.  I would assume that other people can use `BacktestingDatabaseHelper` because they're not using `with`.

As for what you can do now, I would suggest forgetting `with` and using `try ... finally` instead, rather than trying to add your own version of `__exit__` to the object.  You'll just have to make sure you release the handler properly (how you do this will depend on how `BacktestingDatabaseHelper` is supposed to be used), e.g.

```
try:
    handler = self.db
    // do stuff
finally:
    handler.close()
```

---

**Edit**:
Since you can't change it, you should do something like @Daniel Roseman [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10736991/920242) to wrap `BacktestingDatabaseHelper`.  Depending on how best to clean up `BacktestingDatabaseHelper` (as above), you can write something like:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def closing(thing):
    try:
        yield thing
    finally:
        thing.close()
```

and use this as:

```
class mfReportProcess(testingResource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = closing(BacktestingDatabaseHelper.fromConfig('db_name'))
```

(this is directly from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing)).

Comment: Unfortunately, that 'with' line is in part of the common code that I can't change, so I have to use it.

Comment: (My response was too long for a comment, so I've edited my answer.)

Comment: Besides, I am not sure if it is just closing what the context manager is up to do, or if it servers to something else (transaction management etc.)

Comment: Besides as well, you approach only works if the `with` stuff is executed at most once.

Comment: @glglgl I can't be positive, of course, but generally once you've used something in a `with` statement, it's closed and finished with.  In general, you wouldn't expect to be able to re-use a `close`d object -- e.g. a `file` object will [throw an error](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.close) if you try to re-use it.

Comment: Hmm, that seemed to be working better but started getting follow-on errors that suggests it won't work...couldn't seem to then find any of the other methods in the Helper class...

Comment: @karaken12 Look for example at `threading.Lock`: you can use it as often as you want, and it works as a context manager. CMs are not only for closing, hey are useful for other stuff as well. In the case of closing, you are right, though.

Comment: @glglgl Yes, I see what you mean, and interestingly it's mentioned in the PEP that "Many context managers ... will be single-use objects." and "It isn't coincidental that all of the standard library context managers that support reuse come from the threading module".  It also seems like contextlib doesn't handle the reusable case, so you'd have to use something like your own answer above, or (my preferred method) wrap it in a generic `ReClosable` object.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the [`contextlib.contextmanager`](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator to wrap your object so that it supports the context manager protocol.